# How to define knockout data model for given situation?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My data model is as given below.

```
Module
    Fields (ObservableArray)
    Actions(ObservableArray)
        Fields (?)
            name (dyanmic from field list)
            type (dynamic from field list)
            selected (entered by user in UI)
```

Module is main object. Fields and Actions are observable arrays. Field lists under each action needs to be have updated field list and also will have an additional property which is captured from UI.

How the Fields under action model should be populated? Fields list under each action will have unique value for selected field.

Do I need to subscribe to fields ObservableArray and manipulate the Fields list under each action manually or is there any other better way doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate `Fields`? Can't you put everything in the same place?

Comment: Where I display all the fields can be included in the action. User in UI will select whether he/she wants the field for the actions. When ever new field is added the list in action should change

Answer (score 3):

This is how I handle this situation

http://plnkr.co/edit/sWVqrFHdzWUXob42xS7Z?p=preview

Javascript

```
var childObject = function(data){
  var self = this;

  //No special mapping needed here, the mapping plugin does it for us
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

  this.Select = function(){
    self.selected(!self.selected());
  };
};



var parentObject = function(data){
  var self = this;

  //Map the object to myself, using the mapping object we made earlier
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

  //Remap the actions column to observable's
  this.Actions = ko.observableArray(_.map(self.Actions(), function(item){
    return new childObject(item);
  }));

};

var myViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;

  this.RootObject = ko.observable();

  var objectData = {
    "Fields": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Actions": [
      {
        "name": "David",
        "type": "string",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Nish",
        "type": "string",
        "selected": true
      }]
  };

  this.Init = function(){
    //Pass the object data to the parent object.
    self.RootObject(new parentObject(objectData))
  };
};

$(function(){
  myApp = new myViewModel();
  myApp.Init();

  ko.applyBindings(myApp);
})
```

Html

```
     <div data-bind="with: RootObject">
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Selected</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: Actions">
            <tr data-bind="click: Select">
              <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: selected"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```